# SQL trouble with a sql query

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, ms-access

Here is the question with my attempted query below.

For each order, list the order number, order date, part number, part description, and item
class for each part that makes up the order

The data base has a Order_Line table which consists of order_num, Part_num, Num ordered, and quoted_price. It also has an order table with order_num, order_date, and Customer_num.  The third table that this query uses is the part table  which has Part_num, description, On_Hand, Class, Warehouse and Price.  It appears I have to join all three tables.  Here is the query I tried.

```
Select Orders.Order_Num, Order_Date, Part.Part_Num , Description, Class 
From Orders, Customer, Part  
Where Orders.Order_Num = Order_Line.Order_Num
And  Order_Line.Part_Num = Part.Part_Num
```

Comment: You are selecting from `Part` table but it is nowhere to be found in your from clause, also how Orders and Customers tables are related ???

Comment: Especially since you are new to sql you need to not pick up the habit of separating tables with commas and then using where predicates to make the join. This was replaced in ANSI-92 over 25 years ago by the newer join syntax.

Comment: https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins

Comment: I forgot to add the part in from which was a just a typo. I have updated that in the post however that didn't work after I added part in from.  The updated result I have is Select Orders.Order_Num, Order_Date, Part.Part_Num , Description, Class 
From Orders, Customer, Part  
Where Orders.Order_Num = Order_Line.Order_Num
And  Order_Line.Part_Num = Part.Part_Num

Comment: Arg! don't fix your code in a comment, fix it in your question, please!, OK?! ;-) Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select *        --<-- use two part names here  
From       Customer
INNER JOIN Orders     ON Customer.CustomerID = Orders.CustomerID  --<-- Only guessing
INNER JOIN Order_Line ON Orders.Order_Num = Order_Line.Order_Num
INNER JOIN Part       ON Order_Line.Part_Num = Part.Part_Num
```

You haven't mentioned how you want to join customers table with orders in your query which gives you a Cartesian product of them two tables.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a table and seem to have an extra table in your from list:

You may be trying to do this:

```
Select Orders.Order_Num, Order_Date, Part.Part_Num , Description, Class 
From Orders
inner join part on 
 Order_Line.Part_Num = Part.Part_Num
inner join OrderLine on 
  Orders.Order_Num = Order_Line.Order_Num
```

-- cannot tell on what columns  'customer' table can be joined....

Comment: Sorry M. Ali we have almost (the same) solution - I was trying to make sense of what Jacob posted.

Comment: Thank you for the time to come up with a solution. As someone brand new to sql I am very lost in the recommended way you posted. It appears like your answer is the recommended more modern way of doing seems(which seems in conflict with how the book I have lays thinks out) My answer was based on the way the college book I have laid out a similar problem. Is the the way of doing it as I laid it out above wrong or just bad and dated practice.

Comment: You want to list how to connect the tables (join) using the syntax (which is post 1988 syntax) for every table that you are going to get columns from. Pretend that you are instructing a clerk on how find the data. You would start with one table (lets say customers) and for every customer find every order line  based on the order_num column. And so on for the other tables.